# Using Boolean to determine 5-way Where clause

Tags: sql, boolean, logic, where-clause

I'm looking at 5 different columns (db made badly unfortunately). If of the five columns two have one "1" value and one "2" value I want this record to be excluded from the results. However, if it only has one of the two values I want it to be included.

I have this so far, but I'm certain it will not include the record if it has even one of the two values.

```
    NOT ((Ew.DocRecvd1 = 10 OR Ew.DocRecvd1 = 11) OR 
(Ew.DocRecvd2 = 10 OR Ew.DocRecvd2 = 11) OR 
(Ew.DocRecvd3 = 10 OR Ew.DocRecvd3 = 11) OR 
(Ew.DocRecvd4 = 10 OR Ew.DocRecvd4 = 11) OR 
(Ew.DocRecvd5 = 10 OR Ew.DocRecvd5 = 11))
```

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: what you're trying to do isn't very clear, can you show us some example data telling us which should and should not be included?

Comment: Your text talks about `1` and `2`, but your code uses `10` and `11`. What do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you count the number of values in each group that you want.  And, I would do it in a subquery, just because that makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Here is an example:

```
from (select t.*,
             ((case when Ew.DocRecvd1 in (10, 11) then 1 else 0) +
              (case when Ew.DocRecvd2 in (10, 11) then 1 else 0) +
              (case when Ew.DocRecvd3 in (10, 11) then 1 else 0) +
              (case when Ew.DocRecvd4 in (10, 11) then 1 else 0) +
              (case when Ew.DocRecvd5 in (10, 11) then 1 else 0) +
             ) as Num1s,
             <something similar> as Num2s
      from table t
     ) t
where Num1s = 2 and Num2s = 1;
```

Comment: I think I understand this!!!
So, if I wanted to exclude any records with BOTH 10 and 11 in two of the five then I would do
NOT num1s= 2
Right?

Comment: @user3191081 . . . I think so.  That would exclude any row where two columns contained either `10` or `11`.

Comment: I've been working at this a few hours to no avail. It may work, but my experience is limited to doing something like this.

Comment: @user3191081 . . . Modifying your question to have sample data and desired results would help me (or anyone) provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I think yours actually worked, it's like what I wrote down below, however I don't understand the "in (10,11)". Does that mean is 10 or 11 are within the Ew.DocRecvd then it will result in the THEN statement, and if not to the ELSE statement?

Comment: @user3191081 . . . Yes.  The `in` evaluates to true when the left hand side matches any of the values in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You state the filter conditions simply in the `where` clause. Given a table

```
create table foobar
(
  id int not null primary key ,
  c1 int not null ,
  c2 int not null ,
  c3 int not null ,
  c4 int not null ,
  c5 int not null ,
)
go
```

You can say

```
select *
from foobar
where not (     2 = case c1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c2 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c3 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c4 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c5 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
            and 1 = case c1 when 2 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c2 when 2 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c3 when 2 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c4 when 2 then 1 else 0 end
                  + case c5 when 2 then 1 else 0 end
          )
```

The other approach which might run faster is to use as mask table, containing the conditions you want to exclude. Something like this one:

```
create table mask
(
  c1 tinyint null ,
  c2 tinyint null ,
  c3 tinyint null ,
  c4 tinyint null ,
  c5 tinyint null ,
  unique clustered ( c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) ,
)
```

In your case, there are only 30 conditions to be excluded:

```
c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
NULL NULL 1    1    2
NULL NULL 1    2    1
NULL NULL 2    1    1
NULL 1    NULL 1    2
NULL 1    NULL 2    1
NULL 1    1    NULL 2
NULL 1    1    2    NULL
NULL 1    2    NULL 1
NULL 1    2    1    NULL
NULL 2    NULL 1    1
NULL 2    1    NULL 1
NULL 2    1    1    NULL
1    NULL NULL 1    2
1    NULL NULL 2    1
1    NULL 1    NULL 2
1    NULL 1    2    NULL
1    NULL 2    NULL 1
1    NULL 2    1    NULL
1    1    NULL NULL 2
1    1    NULL 2    NULL
1    1    2    NULL NULL
1    2    NULL NULL 1
1    2    NULL 1    NULL
1    2    1    NULL NULL
2    NULL NULL 1    1
2    NULL 1    NULL 1
2    NULL 1    1    NULL
2    1    NULL NULL 1
2    1    NULL 1    NULL
2    1    1    NULL NULL

(30 row(s) affected)
```

The actual query is trivial then (and if you have a *covering index* on the columns to be tested, the test is done with index seeks and so should perform extremely well:

```
select *
from dbo.foobar t
where not exists ( select *
                   from mask m
                   where t.c1 = m.c1
                     and t.c2 = m.c2
                     and t.c3 = m.c3
                     and t.c4 = m.c4
                     and t.c5 = m.c6
                 )
```

The advantage of this approach is that the ruleset is *table-driven*, meaning future changes to the rules are just data modifications to your mask table.

You could also use a positive set of rules, but in your case, the set is bigger (>200 positive cases as opposed to the 30 negative cases).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've found the result I wanted.

I used the following in the WHERE clause of my query:

```
 NOT
     (2 =
     (CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd1 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd3 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd4 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd5 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd1 = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd2 = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd3 = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd4 = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
     CASE WHEN Ew.DocRecvd5 = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
```

It is only possible in my DB to get these two documents in one of five places within one record, so the count could not go over 2 with the two documents i'm looking for.

Kudos to Nicholas Carey and Gordon Linoff for keying me into what I could do and look for!